# Do I have to be concerned about the overhead of `Rc`?

Tags: rust

Am I right to assume that the only thing that "slows down" `Rc`s is that it checks whether to deallocate the object when it drops? Besides that, "how much" is the overhead of dereferencing a `Rc`, i.e. should I be concerned about it?
Are those two functions almost equally fast? Or is there a notable difference in speed?

```
fn test_with_box() {
    let b = Box::new(1.0);
    let x = b * 2;
}

fn test_with_rc() {
    let rc = Rc::new(1.0);
    let x = rc * 2;
}
```

Since the referenced object in `test_with_rc()` always only has one reference and behaves like a `Box` in that function (viewed from outside, not internally, of course).

I suspect that `Rc`s are actually faster than I think.

PS: When talking about "fast" I mean both dereferencing and allocating/deallocating.

Comment: As always with performance questions, the only way to know is to profile it in-situ. Micro-benchmarks are not suitable.

Comment: But it's still interesting to know if the overhead is in the range of a few cycles, a few microseconds, a few milliseconds etc :-) . And Rc is apparently more in the "a few cycles" range.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Rc<T>` is very, very cheap. It’s not as cheap as `T` by quite a bit (boxing values is comparatively expensive in micro-optimisation terms), but scarcely less efficient than `Box<T>`.

It’s just like `Box`, but with an additional couple of words for the strong and weak reference counts, and the only things that need to touch that are creating an `Rc` (initialises the values), cloning an `Rc` (increments the refcount), dropping an `Rc` (decrements the refcount and runs the destructor if appropriate), and downgrading to/upgrading from `Weak` (increments one and decrements the other of the two refcounts).

Dereferencing is a simple memory operation just like it is with `Box`.

Comment: I would just like to add that downgrade/upgrade was stabilized in [Version 1.4.0, 2015-10-29](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-140-2015-10-29)

Answer (score 11):

To answer your question, you can turn to the `test` crate, which contains a benchmarking solution (this needs a nightly):

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

use std::rc::Rc;

fn test_with_box() {
    let b = Box::new(1.0);
    test::black_box(*b * 2.0);
}

fn test_with_rc() {
    let rc = Rc::new(1.0);
    test::black_box(*rc * 2.0);
}

#[bench]
fn bench_box(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    b.iter(test_with_box)
}

#[bench]
fn bench_rc(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    b.iter(test_with_rc)
}
```

Now compiling & running this:

```
$ rustc --test -O rc.rs && ./rc --bench

running 2 tests
test bench_box ... bench:          22 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_rc  ... bench:          22 ns/iter (+/- 0)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured
```

What happened? The RC apparently was completely compiled out. As it should be, because we haven't **cloned** it. So changing the respective `fn` to:

```
fn test_with_rc() {
    let rc = Rc::new(1.0);
    test::black_box(*rc.clone() * 2.0);
}
```

We get the following:

```
running 2 tests
test bench_box ... bench:          23 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test bench_rc  ... bench:          25 ns/iter (+/- 1)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured
```

So, suffice to say, you'll probably need to worry about other things before looking at RC-induced overhead.

Comment: *The RC apparently was completely compiled out* I don't think you can claim that it is optimized out. If you look at the [LLVM IR](http://is.gd/AB68e3), you can see that `test_with_box` calls `@je_mallocx(i64 8, i32 0)` and `test_with_rc` calls `@je_mallocx(i64 24, i32 0)`, so the two blocks wouldn't be the same assembly. There's also 4 more instructions for the `Rc` case.