# Rust – moved variable forbids to borrow itself ("dropped here while still borrowed")

Tags: rust, move, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a program that generates mathematical expressions and then evaluates them. Expressions can contain primitive operations (plus, minus, etc.) or other sub-expressions that consist of primitive operations.

The problem is that sub-expressions are local for the created expression and won't be needed anywhere else except their parent expression (so, I should not make them static), but I can't move parent expression somewhere, because local sub-expressions considered as dropped even if I move them to the parent expression struct.

Minimal example:

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f83d945c495a2f8e76adf65443903a5)

```rust
trait Operation {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32;
}

struct SumNumbers {
    pub numbers: Vec<i32>,
}
impl Operation for SumNumbers {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
        let mut result = 0;
        for x in &self.numbers {
            result += x;
        }
        result
    }
}

struct Expression<'a> {
    pub operations: Vec<&'a dyn Operation>,
    sub_expr_holder: Vec<Expression<'a>>,
}

// Not working attempt to ensure sub_expr_holder will live longer than operations
// struct Expression<'a, 'b : 'a> {
//     pub operations: Vec<&'a dyn Operation>,
//     sub_expr_holder: Vec<Expression<'a, 'b>>,
// }

impl Operation for Expression<'_> {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
        let mut result = 0;
        for operation in &self.operations {
            result += operation.compute();
        }
        result
    }
}

fn build_single_expression() {
    let static_sum2 = SumNumbers {
        numbers: vec![1, 1],
    };
    let static_sum4 = SumNumbers {
        numbers: vec![1, 3],
    };
    let static_sum6 = SumNumbers {
        numbers: vec![4, 2],
    };

    let root_expr = {
        let local_expr_sum10 = Expression {
            operations: vec![&static_sum4 as &dyn Operation,
                             &static_sum6 as &dyn Operation],
            sub_expr_holder: vec![]
        };

        let mut root_expr = Expression {
            operations: vec![],
            sub_expr_holder: vec![local_expr_sum10]
        };
        root_expr.operations = vec![&root_expr.sub_expr_holder[0], &static_sum2];

        // Ideal option would be to keep it immutable:
        // let root_expr = Expression {
        //     operations: vec![&local_expr_sum10, &static_sum2],
        //     sub_expr_holder: vec![local_expr_sum10]
        // };

        root_expr
    };

    let root_expr = &root_expr as &dyn Operation;
    let result = root_expr.compute();
    assert_eq!(result, 12)
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
error[E0597]: `root_expr.sub_expr_holder` does not live long enough
  --> src/gep_tools/test.rs:61:38
   |
50 |     let root_expr = {
   |         --------- borrow later stored here
...
61 |         root_expr.operations = vec![&root_expr.sub_expr_holder[0], &static_sum2];
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
70 |     };
   |     - `root_expr.sub_expr_holder` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Even though I move the `local_expr_sum10` into the `root_expr`, the compiler says it doesn't live long enough to be borrowed from `root_expr.operations`. It seems the second error explains why:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `root_expr` because it is borrowed
  --> src/gep_tools/test.rs:69:9
   |
61 |         root_expr.operations = vec![&root_expr.sub_expr_holder[0], &static_sum2];
   |                                      ------------------------- borrow of `root_expr.sub_expr_holder` occurs here
...
69 |         root_expr
   |         ^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         move out of `root_expr` occurs here
   |         borrow later used here
```

As I understand, the compiler assumes that I can move the `root_expr.sub_expr_holder` out of the `root_expr` struct and it will be dropped while still borrowed by `root_expr.operations`.

Is there a way how I can force the compiler to forbid move of `root_expr.sub_expr_holder` out of the struct and therefore let me borrow it? Or any other approach that will let me borrow the local sub-expressions this way?

**Edit:**
I want to use references specifically, because there may be a lot primitive expressions which are reused among all the expressions and it would be waste of memory to copy them each time. Also, the sub-expressions can be used in the root expression several times:

```rust
root_expr.operations = vec![&root_expr.sub_expr_holder[0], &static_sum2, &root_expr.sub_expr_holder[0]];
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense in this minimal example, but in my full code arguments can be passed to the sub-expressions, so it makes sense to put them in a single expression several times. So, again, it would be a waste of memory to copy them multiple times.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make a self-referential data structure. Do you really need references there?

Comment: What’s the point of storing things in a `sub_expr_holder` `Vec` instead of more directly in `operations` (which will actually work)? Also, `Vec`s and fields can only hold things of a known size, which “any `Operation`” isn’t (I assume `result += operation.compute();` is a placeholder?); consider `Box<dyn Operation>` or making `Operation` an enum. (If you didn’t specifically want to make it a trait, I would definitely recommend the enum.)

Comment: @Ry- I need to use references of the `Expression`'s, because I need to put trait objects to the vector. The code I provided is fully working example, without any placeholders. It will work if you move the root_expr out of the braces scope. Everything works with references if I only use the primitive `Operation`s. Is there no way to include `Expressions` as trait object references to the vector?

Comment: @tadman instead of self-referential struct, I can create new `RootExpression` struct that will be type of `root_expr` (what I actually have in my full code), this doesn't change anything

Comment: No, there’s no way to do that, or even start to do that, but like I said, you can have a `Vec<Box<dyn Operation>>`.

Comment: You don't need to use references to use traits. Ry has the right idea with `Box` which wraps an arbitrary thing.

Comment: Okay, you're both right, the option with Box-es works, thank you! But let's imagine I have lots of such "primitive operations" like that `static_sum6`. All primitives are static and can be reused in different expressions. It will be a waste of memory to copy them around to each expression instead of referencing them. In this case, do I create a static "reference holder" for each primitive and copy/move it around or there's a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Another example would be to use the sub-expression in the root expression several times, like this: `root_expr.operations = vec![&root_expr.sub_expr_holder[0], &static_sum2, &root_expr.sub_expr_holder[0]];`, this is a common case for my program

Comment: If copying expressions is problematic I would use `Rc`. You're definitely trying to create a self-referential struct, see [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone marked this question as a duplicate of "self-referential struct problem" (it was re-opened since then), but as I said, this is just 1 of my attempts to solve my problem. As it turned out, the actual problem is called "Multiple Ownership" and as Chayim Friedman suggested, it can be solved with `Rc`.

As a simple conclusion: if you need to use a local struct that will be dropped at the end of the scope, but you can not move it and have to use references, then go with a reference counter.

A good place to read about `Rc` and multiple ownership is the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html).

My solution:

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a85ff8e97355cd73160e20a8d8d19561)

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Operation {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32;
}

struct SumNumbers {
    pub numbers: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Operation for SumNumbers {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
        let mut result = 0;
        for x in &self.numbers {
            result += x;
        }
        result
    }
}

struct Expression {
    pub operations: Vec<Rc<dyn Operation>>,
}

impl Operation for Expression<> {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
        let mut result = 0;
        for operation in &self.operations {
            result += operation.compute();
        }
        result
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn build_single_expression() {
        let static_sum2 = SumNumbers {
            numbers: vec![1, 1],
        };
        let static_sum4 = SumNumbers {
            numbers: vec![1, 3],
        };
        let static_sum6 = SumNumbers {
            numbers: vec![4, 2],
        };

        let root_expr = {
            let local_expr_sum10: Rc<dyn Operation> = Rc::new(
                Expression {
                    operations: vec![Rc::new(static_sum4),
                                     Rc::new(static_sum6)]
                });

            Expression {
                operations: vec![Rc::clone(&local_expr_sum10),
                                 Rc::clone(&local_expr_sum10),
                                 Rc::new(static_sum2)],
            }
        };

        let root_expr = &root_expr as &dyn Operation;
        let result = root_expr.compute();
        assert_eq!(result, 22)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how good this solution is, but it completely solves my problem, and it [should not affect performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264670/do-i-have-to-be-concerned-about-the-overhead-of-rc).